# jQuery table row highlight onClick and restore onChange alternating css classes

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

First post and new to jQuery. Looked hard but did not find a fully relevant post.

Have alternating row colours in a table; one class NULL/empty one class=alt. jQuery script partially works to highlight the row when clicked.

Question is: how do you use removeClass and then restore (addClass/toggleClass) the specific class that was removed on an onChange event?  Any help appreciated. Tks. (See Fiddle below)

HTML

```
    <table id="fooBar" border="0">
    <tr>
        <th>Text</th>
        <th>Text</th>
        <th>Text</th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="">
        <td>Text</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>image</td>
        <td>image</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="alt">
        <td>Text</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>image</td>
        <td>image</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="">
        <td>Text</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>image</td>
        <td>image</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="alt">
        <td>Text</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>image</td>
        <td>image</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

CSS

```
table {
    width:100%;
    border-collapse:collapse;
    table-layout:auto;
    vertical-align:top;
    margin-bottom:15px;
    border:1px solid #999999;
}

th {
    font: bold 11px"Trebuchet MS", Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #F2EDEB;
    border-right: 1px solid #C1DAD7;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #C1DAD7;
    border-top: 1px solid #C1DAD7;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 6px 6px 6px 12px;
    background: #522D25 url(images/bg_header.jpg) no-repeat;
}

tr {
    background: #fff;
    color: #261F1D;
}

tr:hover, tr.alt:hover {
    color: #261F1D;
    background-color: #E5C37E;
}

.highlighted {
    color: #261F1D;
    background-color: #E5C37E;
}

tr.alt {
    background: #F5FAFA;
    color: #B4AA9D;
}

td {
    border-right: 1px solid #C1DAD7;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #C1DAD7;
    padding: 6px 6px 6px 12px;
}
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("tr").click(function () {
        $(this).closest("tr").siblings().removeClass("highlighted");
        $(this).toggleClass("highlighted");
    })
});
// Note: currently only works for row without '.alt' css class assigned (ie. empty)
// question is how to replace a class and then RESTORE the class onChange
```

Here is the jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/codeChaos1988/kh4VY/1/

Also any pointers on best tutorial sites for actually learning to program in javascript/jQuery would be appreciated as well.

Thank you for your help in advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

So that you don't have to worry about removing/restoring the original class, try changing your css to:

```
.highlighted {
    color: #261F1D !important;
    background-color: #E5C37E !important;
}
```

For JS:

```
$('table').on('click', 'tr', function () {
    var state = $(this).hasClass('highlighted');
    $('.highlighted').removeClass('highlighted');
    if ( ! state) { $(this).addClass('highlighted'); }
});
```

Comment: Thank you thatthatisis.  Worked perfectly!  Hope other users can make use of this post. Cheers!!!

Answer (score -1):

Added this in datatable initialisation section:

```
"createdRow": function( row, data, index ) {
            if (tableInitialized){
                flashRow( row );
            }
```

This worked!